# How to ask child component to access it's html template and show something on UI from parent component using component's class instance?

Tags: angular, metadata, parent-child, viewchild

I am working on one project in which,
I have 2 component :

1. Main component,
2. Popup component

### **Main Component TS:**

```
popupCompo = new popupComponent();

onButtonClick() {
   popupCompo.showModal();
}
```

### **popup Component TS :**

**==> HTML**

```
<ng-template #popup>
...
</ng-template>
```

**==> TS :**

```
@Viewchild("popup") popupElement : Elementref;

constructor(public modalService: NgbModalService) {}

showModal() {
   console.log("popupElement", this.popupElement);         // undefine
   this.modalService.open(this.popupElement, {...});
}
```

`console in above child's function will be undefined if showModal() is called from parent on button click.`
`If showModal() function will click from child component, then it will put log without any undefine.`

I can't move html template at any other places.

StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-component-th9dna?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/dy1.component.ts

### It might due to `@viewchild` can't access outside of class.
Is there any this kind of code possible to access child's viewChild reference? :

```
onButtonClick() {
   popupCompo.showModal.bind(popupCompo)
}
```

So that showModal will call in a context of child component instead of parent class.

How can I show modal from child component , Please guide me what Can I do for access viewchild when call method from parent class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ViewChild` again.

Try this in `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html`:

```
// assign reference variable to child element
<dy1 #child></dy1>
<button (click)="getchildP()">parent : get P</button>
......
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  compo1: any;
  demo = 'string';
  // get a handle on the child component
  @ViewChild('child') dy1Component: Dy1Component;
  constructor() {
    
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  getchildP() {
    // use the reference
    this.dy1Component.getP();
  }
}
```

Your way doesn't work because you're creating a new instance of the child component and not grabbing a handle on the instance that your parent component creates in the HTML.

Comment: That is better way. But I also have to create child component instance in my one service through which I can access it within whole project.
Is there any way to create it in service ?

Comment: Maybe grab the reference from your parent or whoever that is using it using `ViewChild` and then pass the reference to your service. I am not sure how to directly access the component from the service, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Okay Alif, Thanks For answering. I appreciate it.